# Strongly convex cones

Tags: algebraic-geometry

A polyhedral cone is strongly convex if $\sigma \cap -\sigma =\{0\}$is a face. Then here is the following proposition.

Let $\sigma$ be a strongly convex polyhedral cone. Then the following are equivalent.

$\sigma$ contains no positive dimensional subspace of $N_\mathbb{R}$

$\sigma \cap (-\sigma)= \{0\}$

$\dim(\sigma^\vee)=n$

This proposition can be found in almost every paper I can find online which talks about strongly convex polyhedral cones, but I cant find a single one which includes the proof. Anyone who knows a rigorous proof who can help me, or who knows where to find one?

Answer (score 4):

You can likely find a proof in either of Cox, Little and Schenk's *Toric Varieties* or Fulton's *Introduction to Toric Varieties*.  Both are good references for these matters, particularly if you are interested in learning about toric varieties.  Ziegler's *Lectures on Polytopes* is another good source for this information.

Calling your statements $(a)$, $(b)$ and $(c)$, here's a quick sketch:

$(b) \Leftrightarrow (a)$: If $\sigma$ contained a subspace, then $-\sigma$ would contain the same subspace since a subspace is closed under negation.  Thus $\sigma \cap -\sigma = \{ 0 \}$ implies that $\sigma$ contains no subspace besides the $0$ subspace.  Conversely, if there was a non-zero vector $v \in \sigma \cap -\sigma$, then it follows easily that $\mathbb{R}v$ (the subspace spanned by $v$) belongs to $\sigma$.

$(c) \Leftrightarrow (b)$:  Suppose $v$ is a non-zero vector in $\sigma \cap -\sigma$.  Then we claim that $\sigma^{\vee}$ is contained in $M_{\mathbb{R}} \cap v^{\perp} := \{ w \in M_{\mathbb{R}} : \langle w, v \rangle = 0 \}$.  Since this is an $n-1$ dimensional subspace, it follows that $\sigma^{\vee}$ is not $n$-dimensional, proving $(c) \Rightarrow (b)$.  For the claim, if $w \in \sigma^{\vee}$, then $\langle w, v \rangle \geq 0$ by definition, while $\langle w, -v \rangle \geq 0$ since $-v \in \sigma$ by hypothesis.  Thus $\langle w, v \rangle \leq 0$, so $\langle w, v \rangle = 0$.

For the other direction, suppose $\sigma^{\vee}$ is not $n$-dimensional.  Then $\sigma^{\vee}$ is contained in a hyperplane $H \subseteq M_{\mathbb{R}}$, i.e. there exists $v \in N_{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $\sigma^{\vee} \subseteq M_{\mathbb{R}} \cap v^{\perp}$.  Then $\langle w, v \rangle = 0$ for all $w \in \sigma^{\vee}$ shows that both $v$ and $-v$ belong to $(\sigma^{\vee})^{\vee}$.  Then it is a non-trivial fact that $(\sigma^{\vee})^{\vee} = \sigma$, which gives $v \in \sigma \cap -\sigma$.